# How to create an AWS policy that restricts users from creating a security group that allows all inbound traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm wondering how do I create a policy that restricts users from creating a security group that allows all inbound traffic? Currently in the policy creation, AWS is asking for which service specifically, but I haven't found a service that targets vpc security groups specifically.

Anyone have any suggestions that point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To continuously audit and limit security groups across AWS accounts in an organization, use [AWS Firewall Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/firewall-manager/).

You can read more at the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-continuously-audit-and-limit-security-groups-with-aws-firewall-manager/) announcing these features.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! It definitely fits the use-case, is there any other method for the same use-case since aws firewall manager seems rather pricey?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [custom AWS Config rule](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules/blob/master/python/EC2_SECURITY_GROUP_BADINGRESS/EC2_SECURITY_GROUP_BADINGRESS.py) and [toniblyx/my-arsenal-of-aws-security-tools](https://github.com/toniblyx/my-arsenal-of-aws-security-tools).